# Java - File - mkdirs doesn't make dirs

Tags: java, file, mkdirs

```
new File(filePath, "/classes/").mkdirs();
```

`filePath` is a directory and it exists. `classes` is a new directory, that should be created

I believe that mkdirs thinks that classes is a file and doesn't do anything, but when I execute

```
new File(filePath, "/tyhdtyurtu/classes/").mkdirs();
```

`/tyhdtyurtu/classes/` it's created! How to fix this thing? How to create all needed dirs?

UPD:
Inside this folder I also have classes.jar file and when I try to create /classes/ dir it fails. But when I try to create, for example, classes1, it works. Why?

UPD2:

```
System.out.println(new File(apkName, "classes").exists());
System.out.println(new File(apkName, "classes").mkdirs());
System.out.println(new File(apkName, "classes").exists());
System.out.println(new File(apkName, "classes").isDirectory());
System.out.println(new File(apkName, "classes").getAbsolutePath());
```

Output:

```
false
true
true
true
C:\Users\Admin\Videos\App\classes
```

When I copy the link from output to explorer, I see error message that explorer cannot find this path. And if I'm able to create ANY folder except of this, I don't think I have no any permissions

Comment: you don't need the leading and trailing slashes. Does removing them fix anything?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @JPMoresmau, I tried all cases

Comment: There are no exceptions being thrown?

Comment: could not verify (on Windows)

Comment: Do you know if any exceptions are being thrown?  Did a file named "classes" already exist?  What if you just use "/tysdjksdfsk" instead of a two-level path?

Comment: @espertus, Windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: @mort, no. (one more later, but it's another thing)

Comment: do you have an existing file named `classes` in the directory denoted by `filepath`?

Comment: can you create a classes subdir in windows explorer?

Comment: @wero, Yes, I can. But when I run mkdirs (returns true) and exists (true too), but I cannot access that neither from explorer nor java.

Comment: File.mkdirs() returns a boolean indicating success. You should always be evaluating the return value of this method call and take appropriate actions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257765/mkdirs-not-working-in-windows-7

Comment: did you run chkdsk just in case of errors in the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check 2 things

```
1. you have write permissions
2. the directory exists or not
```

you can refer to the following link

http://www.ekiras.com/2015/06/how-to-create-nested-folders-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Check return value to know whether the dir was created
2. Use Apache Utils FileUtils.html#forceMkdir(java.io.File) to create directory with all parents if parents do not exist

Answer (score 0):

You should code as the followings:

```
 new File(filePath, "classes").mkdirs();
 new File(filePath, "tyhdtyurtu/classes").mkdirs();
```